# Stateless item distribution

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

I'm not sure if there's a name for this problem, but I'm hoping to validate my proposed solution or hear other ideas for solving it. This stems from a real engineering problem I've encountered at work, so a practical solution is preferred over a perfect one.

### The Problem

I have an infinite **queue** of items $I = I_1, I_2, I_3, ..., I_k,...$ where $k$ is the item's sequence number.

I want to send each item to one of $n \ge 1$ destinations $D_1, D_2, ... D_n$, such that:

- a distribution $p$ is followed; where $p(i)$ is the *desired* distribution of items sent to $D_i$
- the distribution "holds" even for smaller subsets of $I$
- only $k$, $n$, and $p$ are known when sending each item $I_k$
- at any point, the number of items thus far sent to each destination is unknown

### Context

The simple solution to this problem is to randomly send each item to a destination according to the distribution $p$. This works for a large number of items, but begins to break down when we look at smaller numbers. In the real world, where items arrive sporadically and over a long amount of time, this is a problem. Consider this scenario:

$n = 2$, and $p(i) = 0.5$; that is, an even distribution over two destinations

Items $I_1$ and $I_2$ arrive. Assigning them randomly means there is a $50\%$ chance that all items are sent to the same destination. If it takes an hour for the next item to arrive, we would be missing our target distribution for a *long time*. While everything may be fine over the course of a day or week, the picture is not so good if you look at spans of a few hours or minutes. This additional requirement is what the solution below attempts to address.

### Proposed Solution

Let's assume that we are able to restrict the problem such that $p(i)$ is divisible by $0.1$ for all $i$, with possible values $0.1$, $0.2$, $0.3$, and so on. In practical terms, a restriction like this is quite acceptable. (More on this later)

For each item $I_k$, select a cohort $c = k\mod{10}$

This means that all items can be assigned to one of $10$ cohorts. Assign cohorts in a "striped" manner to each destination according to $p$, with preference for destinations with higher values of $p$.

For example, given $n = 3$, and $p(1) = 0.5$, $p(2) = 0.3$, and $p(3) = 0.2$ the ten cohorts will be:

```
[1] [2] [3] [1] [2] [3] [1] [2] [1] [1]
```

The number indicates which destination that cohort is sent to. This method works because for any set of 10 consecutive items, the target distribution $p$ is guaranteed to hold. Alternating the cohort assignments helps ensure that the current distribution is never that far away from $p$.

The restriction on $p$ can be loosened if necessary, but this will affect the minimum set of consecutive items for which $p$ is guaranteed to hold. For example, if $p(i)$ must be divisible by $0.01$, with values like $0.01$, $0.02$, $0.03$, and so on, then we need $100$ cohorts and $p$ is only guaranteed to hold after every $100$ consecutive items.

There's also probably a more concise and mathematical way to express the alternating cohorts, but I haven't been able to work it out yet.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this solution, or a different approach I haven't tried.

Comment: Do you have efficiency requirements?  Is it OK to take $O(k)$ time to figure out where to send the $k$th item?  Do you know anything about $p$, or could it be totally arbitrary?

Comment: There aren't any strict efficiency requirements, but I'd be hard-pressed to accept an $O(k)$ runtime, since $k$ is not bound, so it'd take longer and longer to figure out the destination for each subsequent item.

The proposed solution itself, assuming the cohort assignment is baked in, can be implemented as an $O(1)$ algorithm.

Comment: $p$ can have any _shape_, but reasonable restrictions like the one stated are acceptable.

Comment: A pragmatic approach is to keep track of the number of items sent to each destination sent so far, calculate the proportion $q(i)$ of items sent to destination $i$, and send the item to the index $i$ that maximizes $p(i)-q(i)$.  But it seems you've ruled this out with your 4th requirement.  This can be simulated without any memory by, at the $k$th step, repeating the entire process of identifying where you've sent the first $k$ items, but that takes $O(k)$ time, which is too slow.